# df.spatial.to_featureclass produces an empty shapefile

Tags: arcgis-pro, pandas, arcgis-python-api

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.8 and Python 3.7 from the ArcGIS\PRO\bin\Python\envs\arcgis-pro-py3\python.exe.

I have a pandas dataframe from CSV I am trying to get to a shapefile or featureclass for a set of ArcGIS Pro Python tools I am trying to make. When I print the df I get rows and a shape column but the shapefile is empty on output. It did work, then all the sudden it didn't and I cannot see the problem.

```
from pandas import read_csv as pdReadCSV, DataFrame as pdDataFrame, to_datetime as 
pdToDateTime
  from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor

df = pdReadCSV('LatLon.csv')
name = 'out_points'
xCol = 'LONGITUDE'
yCol = 'LATITUDE'
df = pdDataFrame.spatial.from_xy(df, xCol, yCol, sr=4326)
print(df)
df.spatial.to_featureclass(location=name, overwrite=True)
```

I don't get any errors, just an empty shapefile. Print shows records with a SHAPE column. Not sure what is missing now...
Edit: Data Sample

```
INDEX,GROUP,DATE,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
1,1,5/16/2019 11:40,46.17691,-62.536669
2,1,5/18/2019 12:05,46.17691,-62.536669
3,1,5/18/2019 15:00,46.17691,-62.536669
4,1,5/19/2019 15:40,46.537742,-61.464301
5,1,5/20/2019 2:00,46.776094,-61.440869
6,1,5/21/2019 7:00,46.176652,-62.536584
7,1,5/21/2019 9:05,46.176652,-62.536584
```

Basically, it is just Index (int64), Group ID (int64), Date (object) once in the df, and Latitude Longitude coords (float64). The Date is the order to connect the points to make a line.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error in ArcGis Pro 3.2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know, there are 10k records in the df. I have been trying dropna() to drop null fields and I printed the dtypes and they look fine. The only thing I can think of is maybe the datetime object for one of the columns is an issue?

Comment: Can you provide some sample lines of the csv?

Comment: I added 8 lines of sample data to the question. Now it stops at 75 points out of 993084 rows. The only thing I changed was set the spatial df to it's own df called sdf.
sdf = pdDataFrame.spatial.from_xy(df, 'LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE')
sdf.spatial.to_featureclass(location=name, overwrite=True)
It probably has something to do with my data... I am basically trying to remake a process I have in geopandas and shapely as an ArcPro tool but I can only use what comes packaged with the ArcPro Python env. I "can" install other modules but not everyone can so they asked for it to be Arcpy friendly.

Comment: Nevermind, it is the datetime field; if I delete it entirely everything works fine. I tried to convert it to pd.to_DateTime but then I realized datetime[64] isn't compatible with esri featureclasses so now I am looking at how to convert the datetime object to a esri compatible datetime object. 
This question can probably be deleted.

Comment: OK, the 8 lines sample data worked by me.

Comment: Yeah, it works up to 75 then it breaks and I think it is the Date object.